# Wrong week day of month?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdatecomponents

I am trying to get week index of first day of month. But it returns wrong value. I am expecting 2 (monday) but result is 6(friday). May be I missed something.

```
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[dateComponents setDay:1];
[dateComponents setMonth:1];
[dateComponents setYear:2016];

NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
NSDate *date = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComponents];

long weekDay = [calendar component:(NSCalendarUnitWeekday) fromDate:date];
```

Comment: jan 1 st is --> 6 it is in friday., see this http://www.tamildailycalendar.com/tamil_monthly_calendar.php?month=01&year=2016&Submit=Submit,

Comment: your coding is correct

Comment: ... or you mean February, but then you must specify 2 for the month integer.

Comment: yes I mean February mixed indexes of months and week. Thanks for response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

January 1st 2016 was a Friday.